# Does this error mean that node modules cant be found?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, pm2

I think I've seen this error on my local computer when I'm missing a module, but I am trying to start my code with pm2. Is that what the error is seen here?

```
0|my-ba |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/website/index.js:4:1)
0|my-ba |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
0|my-ba |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
0|my-ba |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
0|my-ba |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
0|my-ba |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:32:23)
0|my-ba |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
0|my-ba |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
0|my-ba |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
0|my-ba |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
0|my-ba |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
0|my-ba |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
0|my-ba |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
0|my-ba |   requireStack: [ '/home/user/website/index.js' ]
0|my-ba | }
```

Answer (score 0):

It says it doesn't know how to "start" your app, as it's not in home/user/website/index.js

You need to edit your package.json and see which is the start command and move your files accordingly (or edit, whichever is more convenient)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try some stuff

Comment: Im really sure its there? Thats so weird

Comment: addUser.js  botConfig.js  gitignore       methods       oauth.js           public      verification.js
api.md      config        **index.js**        models        package-lock.json  routes      views
auth.js     config.js     mainDiscord.js  node_modules  package.json       strategies

Comment: Make a screenshot of the directory structure and append it to the original question.

Comment: do you have discord?